# Run multiple XServer instances on the same machine on different processor cores

Tags: x-server, multi-monitor

If I have two separate graphics cards (for the sake of discussion, an NVIDIA Quadro K4000 and Quadro K6000), can I run two separate xserver sessions on two different processor cores, keeping the GPU processing and graphics output separate between the two?

Edit 1: While I understand that multiple xserver sessions can be easily created, I am trying to ensure that the processing being done for one display output does not run away with processing resources and bring down the other.

Edit 2: From my knowledge which agrees with Gilles input, xserver is not a multithreaded application.  So a clarification to my question would be how can I force a second X process to a new thread?  The catch that I feel like I would probably run into is that my mouse/keyboard (as input devices specified in my xorg.conf file) would no longer be allowed to share between the two different X instances.

Comment: The kernel will do that automatically. What do you hope to improve? Did you run into latency problems?

Comment: The lone x process that was running is maxing out the cpu core when both separate instances are idling.

Comment: If you have a single X process, it's normal that it uses a single process (AFAIK the Xorg server isn't multithreaded). Is your question how to get two X server processes to run, one with each card? If you do that then they should end up naturally using whichever code is available for each timeslice.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, your input helped me clarify my original question a little more.  I have edited it above.